# HP Photosmart C4795 printer ink cartriges clogged

Tags: printer

I have not used my HP Photosmart C4795 printer in some time and now ink does not come through.  Could the ink cartridges be clogged?  Can this be corrected? Ink level is still showing within normal limits.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference between an inkjet printer and a laser printer, is that with an inkjet printer, the ink can dry up.

Because of this, the printer heads are usually in the cartridge themselves.

The only way to get this sorted, is to replace the entire cartridge. Do note, if you don't print at least once a month, you will get this problem again. If printing once a month is going to be a problem, look into replacing the printer with a laser printer.